# Display date only on DateTime for foreign key object

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My `RelationshipCodeLookup` table uses as a foreign key the primary key field of the `AgentTransmission` table. There can be only 5 records in the `RelationshipCodeLookup` table with the same `AgentTransmission` primary key.

In order to code this, I simply made a 5 `RelationshipCodeLookup` objects in the `AgentTranmsission` model. Everything works fine (create/edit/delete), however I cannot get the `EffectiveDate` to display only it's date.

**AgentTranmsission**

```
namespace Monet.Models
{
  public partial class AgentTransmission
  {
    public RelationshipCodeLookup RelationshipCode1 { get; set; }
    public RelationshipCodeLookup RelationshipCode2 { get; set; }
    public RelationshipCodeLookup RelationshipCode3 { get; set; }
    public RelationshipCodeLookup RelationshipCode4 { get; set; }
    public RelationshipCodeLookup RelationshipCode5 { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TerminationDate { get; set; }
    public string InactiveReasonCode { get; set; }
    public string RecordStatus { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceType { get; set; }
   }
}
```

**RelationshipCodeLookup**

```
namespace Monet.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(RelationshipCodeLookupMetaData))]
    public partial class RelationshipCodeLookup1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string RelationshipId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EffectiveDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastChangeDate { get; set; }
        public string LastChangeId { get; set; }
    }
    class RelationshipCodeLookupMetaData
    {
        [DisplayName("Effective Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EffectiveDate { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

**View**

```
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RelationshipCode1.EffectiveDate, new { @class = "relCodeDate1" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RelationshipCode1.RelationshipId, new { @class = "relDistCode1", maxlength = 3 })</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RelationshipCode2.EffectiveDate, new { @class = "relCodeDate2" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RelationshipCode2.RelationshipId, new { @class = "relDistCode2", maxlength = 3 })</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RelationshipCode3.EffectiveDate, new { @class = "relCodeDate3" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RelationshipCode3.RelationshipId, new { @class = "relDistCode3", maxlength = 3 })</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RelationshipCode4.EffectiveDate, new { @class = "relCodeDate4" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RelationshipCode4.RelationshipId, new { @class = "relDistCode4", maxlength = 3 })</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RelationshipCode5.EffectiveDate, new { @class = "relCodeDate5" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RelationshipCode5.RelationshipId, new { @class = "relDistCode5", maxlength = 3 })</td>
    </tr>
```

**Screen Shot**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create your own editor template that looks like this (Views/Shared/EditorTemplates):

```
@model DateTime?

@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Then use it like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EffectiveDate, "NullableDate")
```

All this is doing is overriding the default `.ToString()` call which gives you the full date and time.